# UISplitViewController without any visible separators and rounded corners

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I would like to design an iPad app like the image in attach:
This application is done arround a UISplitViewController composed of:
- A ViewController or NavigationController on the left
- Another NavigationController on the right (detail).

The application is woking fine except that i see rounded corners betweens the 2 sides of the UISplitViewController...

What is the solution to have my app working as the app in copy ?

[image: Sample app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to use a split view controller to accomplish this, the controller itself does a lot of work for you but the same effect can be accomplished by a UITableViewController and a ViewController lined up side by side in landscape.

All you need implement is handler code for orientation change, to place the UITableViewController as a popover View trigger by some kind of button and for the other view to fill up the screen in portrait.